# Flow and process to do biometric authentication inside flutter and verification in backend

Tags: flutter, backend, face-detection, biometrics

I would like to build a biometric authenticator (face detector) apps with verification from backend and flutter for client...but I do confused about how the process from client to backend works
so I would like to know is there a way to get face algorithm from flutter (so user takes picture and then flutter do the process to get the face algorithm of user) and then send the algorithm to backend for verification.
Is this the right way/flow to do authentication and verification? If yes, is there a package to convert image of face to face algorithm and then send it to backend?
But if no....how the correct flow to do authentication and verification from flutter to backend